# Facebook like button disappears when not logged in

Tags: facebook-like

I have an issue with the FB like button.

In a web view inside our iOS and Android apps, when the FB like button is pressed and you are not logged in, instead of displaying a login modal as it has previously it just disappears.

This happens for the `iframe` and XFBML versions.

I can also reproduce this when clicking the like button in the mobile browser when viewing https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.

I've logged this with FB Dev but thought I'd try here as well.

Comment: Using the debug tool didn't work for me. I've tried using the HTML 5 and FBXML version of the Like button code to no avail. If I'm logged in to FB I see the button, if not, the button is rendered to the page with a width and height of 0.

Did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem....
You have to use this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Enter the url you want to add like button, this will clear facebook cache,
and the like button will work properly.

Comment: what if you are trying to load a facebook page url? then the debugger tells you it can't debug facebook pages :(

Comment: I had the word "kill", in a JS comment, because I was about to kill a layer on DOM.... Unbelievable! Those americans...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible a like button is blocked if the page it links to has a restriction. This article has some more information about this problem: Ttp://www.andreavahl.com/facebook/why-your-facebook-like-box-is-not-showing-up.php